# shorter code instead of using IF for all the combinations

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I try to add all the combinations using IF but it's a lot to write. If I get the user sign and another user sign for example Aries with Aries I send an output ("high much") but I have 12*12=144 combinations!

Is there any option to do it shorter?

```
    <script>
 function hatama() {
       signYours= $("input[name='sign1']").val()
       signFriend=$("input[name='sign2']").val()


       //Aries
       if (signYours=="Aries" && signFriend=="Gemini")|| (signYours=="Aries" && signFriend=="Leo")|| (signYours=="Aries" && signFriend=="Saggitarious")|| (signYours=="Aries" && signFriend=="Libra")||(signYours=="Aries" && signFriend=="Aquarius")
       $("#output").val("High");
       if (signYours=="Aries" && signFriend=="Aries")||(signYours=="Aries" && signFriend=="Virgo") || (signYours=="Aries" && signFriend=="Capricon") || 
       $("#output").val("Medium");
       if (signYours=="Aries" && signFriend=="Pisces") || (signYours=="Aries" && signFriend=="Cancer")|| (signYours=="Aries" && signFriend=="Scorpio")
       $("#output").val("Low");
       //Taurus 
       if (signYours=="Taurus" && signFriend=="Virgo")|| (signYours=="Taurus" && signFriend=="Capricon")||(signYours=="Taurus" && signFriend=="Taurus")||(signYours=="Taurus" && signFriend=="Cancer")||(signYours=="Taurus" && signFriend=="Scorpio")||(signYours=="Taurus" && signFriend=="Pisces")
       $("#output").val("High");
       if (signYours=="Taurus" && signFriend=="Aquarius")||(signYours=="Taurus" && signFriend=="Taurus")
       $("#output").val("Medium");
       if (signYours=="Taurus" && signFriend=="Gemini")|| (signYours=="Taurus" && signFriend=="Leo")||(signYours=="Taurus" && signFriend=="Saggitarious")
       $("#output").val("Low");


</script>
```

Comment: Your current syntax is invalid. `if (signYours=="Aries" && signFriend=="Gemini")||`

Comment: AND set one if(signYours=="Aries") and another 'if' inside that checks the rest like if(signFriend=="Gemini" || signFriend=="Leo"  ....) then $("#output").val("High"); and so on...

Comment: 1. When testing a value against 12 preset options, don't use `if`, use `switch`. 2. Better yet, don't use `switch`, use an array/object/map, and do lookup.

Comment: Also note that you set Taurus & Taurus twice (once in 'high', once in 'medium') and you don't check Aries & Taurus anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use an object whose properties are your signs, whose values are objects with `High`, `Medium` and `Low` properties, whose values are the associated signs:

```js
// Object indexed by your own sign:
const signs = {
  Aries: {
    High: ['Gemini', 'Leo', 'Saggitarious', 'Libra', 'Aquarius'],
    Medium: ['Aries', 'Virgo', 'Capricon'],
    Low: ['Pisces', 'Cancer', 'Scorpio']
  }
  // ...
};
const getAssoc = (signYours, signFriend) => {
  const yourObj = signs[signYours];
  if (!yourObj) {
    return "Your sign is invalid";
  }
  const foundEntry = Object.entries(yourObj)
    .find(([_, arr]) => arr.includes(signFriend));
  if (!foundEntry) {
    return "Friend's sign is invalid";
  }
  return foundEntry[0];
};
console.log(getAssoc('Aries', 'Gemini'));
console.log(getAssoc('Aries', 'Scorpio'));
```

So, for your code:

```
function hatama() {
  const signYours = $("input[name='sign1']").val();
  const signFriend = $("input[name='sign2']").val();
  $("#output").val(getAssoc(signYours, signFriend));
}
```

(make sure to always declare variables, else you'll implicitly create properties on the global object, which should be avoided)

If you need to make properties on `signs` for every possible sign, there may be an even more efficient way, *if there is a pattern to the High/Medium/Low associations.*

Answer (score 1):

IMHO the problem here is to have a well structured data instead of a sequence of IF statements, checkout my solution by configuration:

```js
const signs = [
  {
    userSign: "Aries",
    associations: [
      {
        signs: ["Gemini","Leo", "Sagittarius", "Libra", "Acquarius"],
        val: "High",
      },
    // further match
    ]
  },
  // furter signs
 ]

getMatchValue = (user1, user2) => {
   let result;
   const user1Sign = signs.find(
     (sign) => sign.userSign === user1
   );
   user1Sign.associations.forEach(
    (association) => {
      if(association.signs.includes(user2)){
        result = association.val;
      }
    }
   )
   return result;
}

console.log(getMatchValue("Aries", "Gemini"));
```